# assign selectlist based on another

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My view model looks like this:

```
public IList<TeamCategory> TeamCategories { get; set; } 
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TeamCategoriesList { get; set; }
 public IList<CategoryInput> CategoryInputs { get; set; }

public class CategoryInput
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> VenueList { get; set; }
}
```

Query:

```
foreach (var teamCategory in model.TeamCategories)
            {
                var categoryInput = new CategoryInput()
                {
                    CategoryName = teamCategory.Name,
                    VenueList = teamCategory.Venues.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Value = x.Id,
                        Text = x.Address
                    }),
                };

                model.CategoryInputs.Add(categoryInput);
            }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("TeamCategory", Model.TeamCategoriesList, new {@id = "categorieslist"})

@Html.DropDownList("Venue", new List<SelectListItem>(), new {@id = "venuelist" })
```

So it starts off with teamcategories list being populated, and an empty venue list, then when I change the category, I'd like the venue list to be updated to the list associated with that category as can be seen from the query.

I've started the event listener, but after that I'm at a loss:

```
$('#categorieslist').change(function() {
            AssignVenues();
        });

function AssignVenues() {
                var category = $('#categorieslist').val();

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to the `change` event on the TeamCategory select element,get the selected option value and make an ajax call to your server where you will receive the selected team category id ,get venues for that category id and return the result in JSON format.

```
@section Scripts
{
 <script>
   $(function(){

     $("#categorieslist").change(function(){

         var teamCategoryId=$(this).val();
         $("#venuelist").html("");
         var venues="";

         $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetVenues","Home")/'+teamCategoryId,function(data){
           $.each(data,function(a,b){
              venues+="<option value='"+b.Value+"'>"+b.Text+"</option>";
           });
           $("#venuelist").html(venues);
         });

     });

  });
</script>
}
```

Assuming you have a `GetVenues` method in your `HomeController` which returns a list of SelectListItem's

```
public ActionResult GetVenues(int id)
{
   var list=new List<SelectListItem>();
   // I am hard coding 2 venues. 
   // You may replace it with your real data for the id passed in.

   list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="1", Text="Ann Arbor"});
   list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="2", Text="Detroit"});

   return Json(list,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: fantastic!  It's almost working 100%, the problem I'm running into is passing the teamcategoryId parameter.  With the code as is it just tries to look for a url that looks like:  http://localhost:8050/my-tennis-club/161/team-getvenuesanother%20one  (where 'another one' is the category name). When I take that part off, it works perfectly.  How do I get it to pass that parameter?  I tried the url.action to @Url.Action("GetVenues","Home", new {id = teamcaegoryID}), but of course it won't recognise the variable inside razor

Comment: `@Url.Action("GetVenues","Home", new {id = teamcaegoryID})` wont work as the Url.Action method executes in server before your change event in the javascript. So you need to manually append the javascript variable value to the result of `@Url.Action("GetVenues","Home")`

Comment: right, I got it working by changing it to this:  $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetVenues","Team")' +"?categoryId="+ category...  perhaps you could amend your answer.  Thanks so much Shyju, I'm now on my way to understanding ajax and being able to use it! :-)